# texSubImage2D doesn't update texture

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, opengl-es

I want use OpenGL ES to draw a frame animation, so I use `glTexSubImage2D` to update the texture.

This function initializes the texture:

```
 private void initTexture()
    {
        textures=new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1,textures,0);
        //Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/xiaobizi/xiaobizi_0001.png");
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/aa.png");
        ratio=(float)bitmap.getHeight()/(float)bitmap.getWidth();
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
```

this function to save&remove Bitmap:

```
 mTextureMap.remove(mPathList.get(messageTag));
            mTextureMap.put(mPathList.get(saveCount),BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPathList.get(saveCount)));

private void drawMagic()
    {

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE,GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(programMagic);

        int mPositionHandleFace = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programMagic, "vPosition");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandleFace);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandleFace, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        int mTexCoordLocFace = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programMagic, "a_texCoord" );

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLocFace );

        // Prepare the texturecoordinates

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLocFace, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mTransHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic, "transMatrix");
        int mScaleHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic,"scaleMatrix");
        int mRotateXHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic,"rotateXMatrix");
        int mRotateZHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic,"rotateZMatrix");
        int mRotateYHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic,"rotateYMatrix");

        //control matrix
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mTransHandle,1,false,transMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mScaleHandle,1,false,scaleMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotateXHandle,1,false,rotateXMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotateZHandle,1,false,rotateZMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotateYHandle,1,false,rotateYMatrix,0);
        int mtrxhandleFace = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programMagic, "uMVPMatrix");
        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        //GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandleFace, 1, false, mGLTextureTransformMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandleFace, 1, false, mSecondTransFormMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);

        if(i>=mTotalCount)
        {
            i=i-mTotalCount;
        }
        // update texture

        GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,mTextureMap.get(mPathList.get(i)));
        int mSamplerLocFace = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (programMagic, "s_texture" );
        // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLocFace, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandleFace);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLocFace);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
        mDecodeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
        i++;
    }
```

this is my drawFrame function.
In *initTexture* function if the **bitmap belongs to the Frame Animation**, ***texSubImage2D* works**,the texture always updating, but if i pass a bitmap that **does't belongs to the Frame Animation** , the function *texSubImage2D* **does't work**. In that case, the texture always was the bitmap that i passed in function *initTexture* didn't update.
If i called the function when opengl was dawing, the texture was black,but its shapes can be displayed properly, just the background was black.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to fix this.thank u.

Comment: Are all images of the same size?

Comment: @BDL no, different animation has different size, is the result of this? should i  rebind the texture when use the different animation

Comment: If you use `glTexSubImage`: Yes, the images have to be smaller or the same size. If you want to resize the texture instead of uploading new data to an existing one, use `glTexImage`.

Comment: I think the line GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); at the end of your drawMagic() method is useless and may cause this unexpected behavior.